# Hibernate collections within collections

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, jpa, many-to-many

I have a Hibernate entity named Menu which has a collection of Groups, each group in turn has a collection of MenuItems.  So as an example, a menu can be for a restaurant, groups can be Lunch and Dinner and the menuItems within these can be Pasta, Burger, Salad.

The problem I'm having is that once i have created the menu and saved it (which works fine), when i try to get the menu back I am getting more groups than were originally created.  So taking the example above, if i put Burger and Salad in Dinner group and Pasta in Lunch, I am returned a Menu with THREE (rather than TWO) groups: 2 Dinner groups (each with the items i put in) and 1 Lunch group.  I basically get back as mayny groups as the number of menu items i inserted into each group.  So if i had inserted 4 items, 4 groups are returned. Anyone know why this may be?

The relationships are: Menu to Group = One-to-Many, Group to MenuItems = Many-to-Many

Groups are not reused.  They will be unique to one menu.  But MenuItems can be reused in many groups.

Here is my code:

```
class Menu {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long menuID;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)     
   @JoinColumn(name="menuID")
   private List<MenuGroup> groups;
}

class MenuGroup {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long groupID;

   @Sort (type=SortType.NATURAL)
   @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name="group_menu_item", 
              joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "groupID") }, 
              inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "menuItemID") } )
   private SortedSet<MenuItem> menuItems;
}

class MenuItem {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long menuItemID;
}
```

Comment: @Hisham Can you show how do you retrieve you saved Menu ???

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks for your comment. I am using Spring so i use HibernateTemplate in the following way:  template.get(Menu.class, menuID);

Comment: Do you implement hashCode/equals properly?

Comment: @Pascal: where would I be doing that?  Do you mean for the SortedSet?  I have implemented Comparable on MenuItem, I will go back and tinker with it to make sure THAT is not the problem.  But what could be the problem there?

Comment: See [4.3. Implementing equals() and hashCode()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode). But I don't think it's the problem here (you should provide a valid implementation for MenuItem though). Actually, a test case allowing to reproduce would be really nice.

Comment: @Hisham: can you post queries that hibernate do to retrive your Menu record?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can not comment atm, so it has to be an answer. Pls specify how you retrieve your data + in the java mapping files you could use enum types ! specify lunch / dinner, and fetch relationships.  But pls give more info on how you retrieve fetch your data as well as mapping file !